# Where can I download themes for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2019, color-scheme

My understanding is that there are currently many ways to add new color themes in Visual Studio 2019, but none that really fits my needs:

- The extension `Color Themes for Visual Studio` installs new themes to chose in the native options menu,
- The extension `Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2019` installs a gui to chose and install themes,
- The marketplace that contains a category `Themes` but the selection is scarce compared to the VS Code themes marketplace,
- I also stumbled upon [Dainty](https://dainty.site) which seems nice but a Group Policy won't let me build themes on my machine, plus I'd rather not use third party software (and install node + yarn) since Visual Studio has a native support.

So, what I am looking for is a way to easily find themes so I don't have to create or build one myself.

More specifically, I'd like to install an equivalent of the theme [Winter is Coming Light](https://github.com/johnpapa/vscode-winteriscoming) found in the VS Code marketplace which I cannot use directly in Visual Studio 2019, since they use different theme formats (.vstheme is XML versus JSON for VSCode) and, by extension, any way to browse through a selection of themes as rich as the one we can find on VS Code.

Comment: Update: it seems Dainty has disappeared. The website if offline and the extension is not available in the Visual Studio Market Place anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a themes converter that can take any Visual Studio Code theme and bring it to Visual Studio 2022:

- https://github.com/microsoft/theme-converter-for-vs

It's not just click and install, you actually need to use it with Visual Studio to prepare a VSIX extension, but it's just a few minutes of work and it's well documented.

Answer (score 8):

In VS2019 go to Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Online -> Visual Studio Market Place -> Tools -> Themes ... and you'll have plenty to choose and it includes a link to preview called "More information".

Oh! to use the downloaded theme you should go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General and inside it Color Theme.

Comment: I'm aware of the Market Place as a source for themes but you can only find a mere 70 themes on it, compared to the 4000 available for VS Code.